# What is the most elegant Pythonic way to write an 'if-statement' within a loop?

Tags: python, loops

Here is the operation that I want to perform:

```
        for sample in samples:
            if sample['something'] is None:
                sample['something'] = 'something_else'
```

I want to write this in a more elegant and Pythonic way. It would be great if some experts in Python could help. `samples` is a list of dictionaries.

Comment: You already have it. If you're fishing for a list comprehension, don't. https://stackoverflow.com/q/5753597/843953

Comment: What is samples? A list?

Comment: `sample['something'] = sample['something'] or 'something_else'` which is one line, but much more implicit and I'd stay with your option.

Comment: It's good as it is now.

Comment: What is `sample` - a dict? And it is very much opinion based question.

Comment: `samples` is a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
for sample in (elt for elt in samples if elt["something"] is None):
    sample["something"] = "something_else"
```

Note use of generator expression to not build another in-memory list, though this might be unnecessary.

I also would not use explicit None check either, unless empty collections, strings or 0 should be considered "truthy" values -- often they aren't, with the exception of zero. `if not foo` reads IMO better than `if foo is not None`. If this is your case too, you could do just

```py
for sample in samples:
    sample["something"] = sample["something"] or "something_else"
```

Then again I wouldn't probably bother, original would be good enough for me, and like suggested in comments, using `or` shortcut could be a tad hacky (in a bad way) for some readers.